# assigning a value to the points realized in a point pattern on a network

Tags: spatstat

I am thinking about a possibility with spatstat package in R. When I generate a point process on a linear network (uniform or poisson), is it possible to have the process assign a value (mark) to the generated point? For example: if I use uniform process for 3 points (p1, p2, p3) on the whole network, can I somehow generate a value to assign to this point? So, apart from x,y of each point p; can I generate a mv (markvalue) for each point such that p1 has x1,y1, mv1 or p2 has x2,y2, mv2. Preferably being able to state the range of mv to be between values [a,b]

I do not know how this would be called scientifically and therefore may be I am missing keywords to look in the Baddeley et al textbook on point process by CRC.

Could someone put me onto a correct path to do something like this :)

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, `spatstat` allows for marked point patterns on a linear network. You simply assign the vector of marks after you have generated the points:

```
library(spatstat)
a <- 1; b <- 2
X <- rpoislpp(5, simplenet)
marks(X) <- runif(npoints(X), a, b)
```

Comment: Thank you. Can it be more than marks? for example:  `X$myvariable<-as.marks(vector)` ?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by that. Marks can in principle be any kind of information that you want to attach to the points of the point pattern. It can be a simple number for each point as in my example, a vector of numbers for each point or some complicated object for each point. What info are you trying to attach to each point?

Comment: I want to attach a pipeline or a road damage value, which can be a number (#) of certain kind of surface damages, length or width of a damage etc. So I want to say, at a location the length of damage is valueL, at the same location width of damage is valueW. I think you are already stating what I want, but I am not sure how to define them and how to access them to write to a file. Thank you